# How to change the namespace delimiter in doxygen?

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to parse python codes and generate documentation. However, the namespaces are delimited with `::` in the C++ convention.

How can I change this to `.` as in the python convention?

Comment: If you use a recent enough version of doxygen, it should present the results in the convention that is natural for the language. The language is determined by the file extension (but can be overruled using EXTENSION_MAPPING). Which version of doxygen did you use?

Comment: I was using 1.6 but have updated to 1.8 and discovered just what you mentioned. Thanks.